# How to pass differrent variables into the same template in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have sidebar and here I need to print the different info but in the same design. I created the template file for that. But I don't know how to pass different variables into it.

sidebar.php

```
$related_programs = get_field('related_programs');

if($related_programs): 
    include(locate_template('template_parts/content-related-list.php'));  
endif; 


// the another var should go to the same template
$related_professors = get_field('related_professors');

if($related_professors):
    include(locate_template('template_parts/content-related-list.php')); 
endif;
```

template_parts/content-related-list.php

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($items as $item):?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($item); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($item); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php  
           endforeach; 
           wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
</ul>
```

How to pass these two different variables to the same template so that they will ne known as $items each time?

Answer (score 0):

You should use single if statement instead of double if statements in **sidebar.php**

```
<?php  
$related_programs = get_field('related_programs');
$related_professors = get_field('related_professors');

if(isset($related_programs) || isset($related_professors)):
    include(locate_template('template_parts/content-related-list.php'));  
endif; 
?>
```

And you should use associative array to pass info into same variable `$items`.

```
$dummy_array = array(
    'related_programs'      => get_field('related_programs'),
    'related_professors'    => get_field('related_professors');
);
```

So, you can get `$items['related_programs']` and `$items['related_professors']` into template.

Comment: You just rewrite my code in less lines but no solution. There is $item variable in template file, not $related_programs or $related_professors.

Comment: And do several loops here? You shorted code in sidebar and extended in template part.

Comment: You should just create associative array of both the fields in sidebar. So, it will available in your template having data. Then just do looping in the template. I hope this will work.

Comment: I understand that. But I don't think it is a good solution to do several loops here. What is thepurpose of template in this case?

Comment: How can you achieve your requirement then?

Comment: I hope somebody writes or I may find a solution myself.

Comment: I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($related_programs):
    set_query_var( 'items', $related_programs );
    get_template_part( 'template_parts/content', 'related-list' );
endif;
```

and

```
if($related_professors):
    set_query_var( 'items', $related_professors );
    get_template_part( 'template_parts/content', 'related-list' );
endif;
```